# FTPClient hangs up in middle of of transfer and never times out

Tags: android, timeout, ftp-client

I have a simple FTP upload App that normally works fine.

Sometimes in the middle of a Upload I might lose INTERNET (moving between wifi spots or something).

When this happens the Upload keeps trying to upload but makes no progress, doesn't timeout or cause any errors and since the service never finishes I can't restart it unless I force stop the App.

How can I set timeout options and any other useful tool prevent my App from doing this?

How do I implement and to what effect the following or any other:

```
client.setConnectTimeout(60); //Are this milliseconds, seconds or what?
client.setDefaultTimeout(300); //Are this milliseconds, seconds or what?
client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(120); //Are this milliseconds, seconds or what?
```

Here is a shoetened version of my code for you to see.

myFTP.class

```
public class myFTP{
    String ip;
    String user;
    String pass;
    FTPClient client = new FTPClient();

    public myFTP() {
        ip = "someip";
        user = "´someuser";
        pass = "somepass";
        client = new FTPClient();
    }

    public boolean connect() {
        //Define vars
        try{
            //Connect and login
            client.setConnectTimeout(60);
            client.setDefaultTimeout(300);
            client.setControlKeepAliveTimeout(120);
            client.connect(ip);
            client.login(user,pass);

            if(FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(client.getReplyCode())){
                client.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            }else{
                Log.e ("Coneccion FTP", "Fallo");
            }

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (SocketException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean upload (String fileName, File file, String dir){

        //Cargo el archivo
        try{
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            client.enterLocalPassiveMode();
            Log.e("Subiendo", fileName);
            boolean status = client.storeFile(dir+fileName,fis);
            if (!status){
                fis.close();
                return false;
            }
            fis.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
        try {
            client.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made some changes.

Had the FTP server connect and stay connected for all files instead of connecting and disconnecting for  every file.

Added timeouts after a lot of trying and failing that seem to work.

In the alarm I stopped the service and then started a new one. If the service is hangged up it will start again.